# How to traverse a directory structure to find files

Tags: bash, file, directory, find, traversal

I am trying to create a script that will traverse through my music directory and eventually convert anything over 192bps to 192bps.  So far I have the following...

```
#!/bin/bash

music="/backup/MUSIC/AC-DC/Back In Black"

for file in `find "$music" -type  f -name '*.mp3'`; do
        echo "$file" | cut -d/ -f6-
done
```

but I am getting weird output , like 1 word per line, and not  even the entire file name.  I don't understand what the cut -d/ -f6- is for either...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you get if only `echo "$file"?`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `while` loop instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

music="/backup/MUSIC/AC-DC/Back In Black"

find "$music" -type f -name "*.mp3" | while read file; do
  echo "$file"
done
```